# Web server used to send spam

Tags: spam, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

One of the ubuntu 16.04 servers I operate is being abused for sending spam. There are no user accounts, nobody other than me has shell access.

What I know so far is that this was caused by php scripts being injected via a www-data writeable directory in the web folders (an unfortunate necessity for a web app that's hosted there). So far no existing files have been compromised. A bunch of scripts having showed up in directories where www-data has write permissions, and the server started sending spam.

Rather then killing this machine and setting it up anew with improved security, I'm trying to figure out exactly what happened first, but I'm hitting a wall trying to find where the spam scripts are hidden. Perhaps someone with better sysadmin skills can help me try and locate them?

This is an amazon tiny VM with both packet filter set up to only allow ports 80/443 from anywhere, as well as iptables set up to do the same (to protect the internal interface as well). I only noticed something was wrong because OSSEC told me there were files being written to the web directory that shouldn't be there. A little later, amazon sent an abuse report stating my server had been used to send spam. I've removed the offending scripts as well as any trace I could find of scripts that might be used to trigger hidden spam scripts on the system, but I can't find anything further and the spam keeps re-occurring.

I've poked around the process stack when the spammer scripts are active. I am unable to located the script itself as it appears to remove itself after launch, and it also manages to change its own process name as listed in e.g. ps to exim as well as httpd and possibly others:

```
www-data  4568  0.1  0.7  38440 14492 ?        Ss   21:47   0:00 httpd
www-data  5036  0.1  0.4  32964  9056 ?        Ss   21:50   0:00 exim
```

exim isn't even installed on this server. Looking at details for the exim process:

```
sudo lsof | grep 5036:

exim       5036               www-data  cwd       DIR              202,1     4096          2 /
exim       5036               www-data  rtd       DIR              202,1     4096          2 /
exim       5036               www-data  txt       REG              202,1  1907192        927 /usr/bin/perl
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    27168       6706 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1   102064       6721 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    18696       6704 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    43464       6727 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/Socket/Socket.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    18768       6713 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/IO/IO.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    39224     396841 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1  1864888     396824 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1   138696     399454 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1  1088952     396860 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    14608     396822 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
exim       5036               www-data  mem       REG              202,1   162632     396436 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
exim       5036               www-data    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0          6 /dev/null
exim       5036               www-data    1w      CHR                1,3      0t0          6 /dev/null
exim       5036               www-data    2w      CHR                1,3      0t0          6 /dev/null
exim       5036               www-data    3u     IPv4            7357569      0t0        TCP *:27450 (LISTEN)
exim       5036               www-data   22r     FIFO               0,10      0t0    4428903 pipe
exim       5036               www-data   23w     FIFO               0,10      0t0    4428903 pipe
exim       5036               www-data   24r     FIFO               0,10      0t0    4428904 pipe
exim       5036               www-data   25w     FIFO               0,10      0t0    4428904 pipe
```

So we see this is apparently a perl script masquerading its name as exim, listening on TCP port 27450. That should be fruitless though as there is a physical firewall only allowing ports 80 and 443 from anywhere. The only other port allowed is 22 and that is limited to the admin location using an IP mask.

Further to this, there are iptables set up with the same rules, only allow 80/443 from anywhere, the rest is totally locked down.

In other words, whatever is instructing these scripts to do anything, it comes in via HTTP/HTTPS.

So looking at the httpd process which seems more suspect, we find that this again is a perl process that was launched from /tmp/phpnMv330:

```
ubuntu@XXX:~/bin$ sudo ls -la /proc/4678/exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 0 Dec 24 22:00 /proc/4678/exe -> /usr/bin/perl
```

Also, this seems to be the more active process:

```
sudo lsof | grep 4678

httpd      4678               www-data  cwd       DIR              202,1     4096          2 /
httpd      4678               www-data  rtd       DIR              202,1     4096          2 /
httpd      4678               www-data  txt       REG              202,1  1907192        927 /usr/bin/perl
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    27168       6706 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1   102064       6721 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    18696       6704 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    43464       6727 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/Socket/Socket.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    18768       6713 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1/auto/IO/IO.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    39224     396841 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1  1864888     396824 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1   138696     399454 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1  1088952     396860 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1    14608     396822 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
httpd      4678               www-data  mem       REG              202,1   162632     396436 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
httpd      4678               www-data    0r      CHR                1,3      0t0          6 /dev/null
httpd      4678               www-data    1w      CHR                1,3      0t0          6 /dev/null
httpd      4678               www-data    2w      CHR                1,3      0t0          6 /dev/null
httpd      4678               www-data    4w     FIFO               0,10      0t0     721333 pipe
httpd      4678               www-data    5r     FIFO               0,10      0t0     721334 pipe
httpd      4678               www-data    7u     IPv4            7451383      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:60598->etb-4.mail.tiscali.it:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data    8u     IPv4            7450674      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:48986->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data    9u     IPv4            7450754      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:49146->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   10u     IPv4            7450546      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:48730->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   11u     IPv4            7450866      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:49370->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   14u     IPv4            7450853      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:49344->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   15u     IPv4            7450480      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:48598->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   16u     IPv4            7450824      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:49286->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   17u     IPv4            7450508      0t0        TCP ip-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.internal:48654->mta-v3.mail.vip.gq1.yahoo.com:smtp (ESTABLISHED)
httpd      4678               www-data   22r     FIFO               0,10      0t0     114904 pipe
httpd      4678               www-data   23w     FIFO               0,10      0t0     114904 pipe
httpd      4678               www-data   24r     FIFO               0,10      0t0     114905 pipe
httpd      4678               www-data   25w     FIFO               0,10      0t0     114905 pipe
httpd      4678               www-data   32u      REG              202,1   115271        633 /tmp/phpnMv33O (deleted)
```

I've replaced /usr/sbin/sendmail with a wrapper (as per this post: [Mail spam sending script injected](https://serverfault.com/questions/506142/mail-spam-sending-script-injected)) to report which account is sending the emails, simply to confirm that it is www-data. However, the sendmail wrapper never gets triggered by the scripts, yet all mail ends up in the mail queue. I wonder how that occurs? Sending mail manually using e.g. mail -s "xxx" to@me.com

I can't find any suspicious files in any of the web directories now, I've cleaned them up. I ran maldet which located a few of the bad scripts, but missed at least half of them. There's only one web directory the www-data user has write permissions to. I've also cleaned up /tmp and /var/tmp, both if which had been harbouring spam scripts. OSSEC does not report any new files being written to the web directory www-data can write to. The www-data cronjob that used to run a spam script has been disabled as well (and the target executable removed - which was en ELF binary btw, not a script).

EDIT: I just located a suspicious POST in the apache logs in a old and static wordpress site on the same server which has no write/upload/update permissions anywhere, i.e. is a crippled WP. The POST was to a file that's been there since early August this year. That POST coincided with with spam generation being triggered using a binary located in /var/tmp.

Lessons: Spammers appear to sometimes take their time between injection and abuse of a system. I'm still interested in learning other sysadmin's tricks of the trade to locate such abuses more swiftly. I'm also still stumped as to how it is possible for a perl process to rename itself in ps...